# Why does this factoring method only work for quadratics of the form $x^2 + bx + c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^2-7x+10$

Because the first item is $1x^2$ (the quadratic term has coefficient $1$), we can use the shortcut. The second sign is a plus sign, so we want the sum of $10$'s factors to be $-7$; $10=(-2)(-5)$

$x^2-7x+10=(x-2)(x-5)$

If the last item has a lot of factors, we can use a shortcut, provided the first term is $1x^2$ (the quadratic term has coefficient $1$)

Please explain why you can only use the shortcut if the first term is $1x^2$

Comment: What "shortcut" are you referring to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It may help to try an example where you know what the factored answer is but the coefficient of $x^2$ isn't 1. Take two binomials like $(x+3)(3x+5)$ and multiply them together, then see what your shortcut suggests.

Comment: If you have an coefficient for #x^2$ other than $1$, the rule changes and guessing the correct values becomes difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where the coefficient of $x^2$ isn't $1$, you can still convert the expression into the standard form so that you can apply your formula.

For example, let's say that you want to factorize $2x^2-10x+12$

You just have to factor out the coefficient of $x^2$ to get $2(x^2-5x+6)$

Now, the sum of $6$'s factors should be $-5$; $6=(-2)(-3)$

$2x^2-10x+12=2(x-2)(x-3)$

Now, I'll explain the reason why this works.

When you have a general quadratic expression $x^2+bx+c,\ $you can factorize it into something in the form $(x+\alpha)(x+\beta)$.

$(x+\alpha)(x+\beta)=x^2+\alpha x+\beta x+\alpha\beta=x^2+(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta$

Comparing $x^2+(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta$ and $x^2+bx+c$, we see that $(\alpha+\beta)=b$ and $\alpha\beta=c$

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just factors of $c$, so the problem boils down to finding two factors of $c$, such that their sum $\alpha+\beta$ equals $b$.

Now if $x^2$ didn't have a coefficient of $1$, then we would have to compare the expressions $x^2+(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta$ and $ax^2+bx+c$.

As you can see, no matter what value we choose for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (the factors of $c$), the two expressions cannot be made the same (because $x^2$ is always unequal to $ax^2$ when $a\ne1$).